# What's the matter with the jquery mobile page caching?

Tags: javascript, caching, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile website with jQuery Mobile. I know the framework puts pages in cache so that it can make nice transitions between pages, reduce data transfer and so on.
But in my case it's pretty boring because I think it doesn't execute some JavaScript in my page. I'll explain:

this page presents a form with a date field. I use mobiscroll to make a date-picker appear when the focus is on that field.

When I submit the form, if there's a validation error (I use codeigniter), the server redirects to the form (repopulates the fields etc..) and then the date-picker doesn't work anymore. If I initiate it from the JS console it works again so that's make me think the JS code didn't be re-executed when coming back to the form page.

I added `data-ajax="false"` as attribute of the form to make it work (I lost the pretty transition but I don't really care). Is that the best solution ?

Then I looked for another way to do it definitively because the cache mechanism makes problems in other pages. So I found:

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
});
```

This should be completely deactivating the cache but it's not the case. I tried to remove some `data-ajax="false"` and then I had the same problem as before.

So what's the matter with the page caching mechanism? And why doesn't `$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;` work?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but here are the docs for page caching in jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I just don't want jQuery Mobile to cache or prefetch the pages.

Comment: `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;` is the default.

Comment: Yeah but I still have to put data-ajax="false" attiribute in EVERY links and forms to deactivate the ajax prefetching. I'm just looking for a global solution so that I wouldn't have to put data-ajax="false" everywhere.

Comment: I did look at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html and I tried to set $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false but I still have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the

```
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
```

working and for my problem it was better to do

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

I wasn't loading the .js files in the right order. (see the mobileinit event http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

BUT I'm still wondering why my script wasn't executed after each page load (or whatever for the ajax navigation system).